# Activity indicator for QLPreviewController not displayed

Tags: ios, ios5

I'm using a QLPreviewController to display a quick look of a PDF files and images. Before controller upload content there is a blank screen displayed for those seconds. I try to add activity indicator. It start animating but it is not displayed.

Comment: [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible:YES];

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, so I thought I'd share a possible solution.

It is likely that your main thread is blocked, preventing the QLPreviewController from loading. You could consider loading your data in another thread like this:

```
dispatch_queue_t getData = dispatch_queue_create("com.myDomain.appName", NULL);

dispatch_async(getData, ^{
    //get some data

});
```

Your main thread should now immediately push the QLPreviewController which will display its own Activity Indicator while it retries to get data at the _previewItemUrl. 
For long running tasks, this operation can time out with:

> timed out waiting for fence barrier from com.apple.quicklook.quicklookd

In this case, use performSelectorInBackground:withObject:, and post a notification at the end of the method that it has completed. Register your class to receive the notification, and push the previewController via @selector.